# Update application with SSL certificate data

Tags: android, ssl

I have Android application that connects to MQTT server via secure connection. I'm using user name+password and SSL certificates for this purpose.  Certificates for each user are different.

User knows username and password, but how to locate certificate generated for particular user in my application? I would like to organize everything as less annoying as possible.  Connecting to some FTP server and downloading certificate file not looks nice. What is usual way to solve such problem?

How it is usually organised certificate generation and placing into application procedure?

Comment: Do you have to extend a SSL? Today standard is REST, the security can be a JWT

Comment: @cutiko You mean I should connect to REST server and get certificate there?

Comment: I mean, make a POST to the server with user and password as body, should be https, and that should return a JWT as the body response. That JWT can be used later to validate the user is authenticated.